# youtube video downloader/transcoder on a vps

Tags: video, youtube, html, vps

I have a VPS laying around and was wondering how can I can make a simple webpage with the same basic functionality from this: https://yout.com/

Basically, I don't want a fancy design only a form where can I put the video id, the video quality or mp3 and submit it, and then the VPS let me download it? Any ideas how can I make it? thx

BTW I know I can download youtube-dl to do it, but wanna know how can I make it work on a webpage and in the server side :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
 http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.Your_video_id.'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US
```

above url to get video information ad well as download link. You have to use youtube api for related video link and get number of like or dislike and other thing. You can use this GitHub project. To get download link in your server. Also for more help comment below.

```
https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader
```